# Plywood for Bathroom Subfloor

Tags: bathroom, subfloor, plywood

I've ripped out the floor of my bathroom down to the joists. The bathroom is 5 ft x 4 ft. Should I use tongue and groove or can I use standard plywood? Does it matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to use 1/4" concrete backer board over 1/2" plywood as a bathroom subfloor?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51779/is-it-ok-to-use-1-4-concrete-backer-board-over-1-2-plywood-as-a-bathroom-subfl)

Comment: The linked answer is about what backerboard manufacturers suggest to use at minimum. Were you looking for actual IRC code?

Comment: @Mazura This sounds like his direct question is whether t+g is better than standard plywood. The other thread reads about concrete board. If I missed it let me know

Comment: Backerboard is more important than using T&G or not, IMO. I'm not sure what code says; I just always use 3/4" (whatever) anyway, and not 5/8". - Wait... it's less than the size of a sheet of plywood. It wouldn't matter what type it is, except it's supposed to be exterior grade OSB.

Comment: Backerboard provides no support, the important layer is the plywood which depends on joist spacing with a minimum of 1/2 required @16 oc w/ l/360

Comment: Related: [Should I replace bathroom OSB subfloor with plywood?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49196/should-i-replace-bathroom-osb-subfloor-with-plywood) IMO, the question is whether to use OSB or not. T&G is for new construction, not a small rehab job that's less than the size of a full sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the direction of the joists, it will only take 1 sheet, the T&G will have no value, unless the floor you pulled up was T&G as well, then it will only help on one edge.

If the T&G was cheaper than square edge, then I would use it. I have seen it cheaper in a big box store, although I could not figure out why it was. It was not on sale....

Comment: Actually if the joist run in any direction, it will still take one sheet.

Comment: Plus one; it doesn't matter. What does matter is everything above the page break in my answer on the 'dupe', especially: "*minimum* 5/8" exterior grade"

Answer (score 0):

There are advantages to using t&g.

In terms of substrate requirements, it doesn't matter. A 5/8th sheet of t&g will support the floor just as well as a 5/8th sheet of standard.

For your considerations, with standard you'll have to space them with a 1/8th gap between sheets for expansion/contraction, this isn't a problem with t&g, they can be tightly fit.

Comment: 4X5 bathroom - 4x8 sheet of plywood - ¿What joints? I hardly expect a pre-exsisting T or G joint right at the wall line where the old floor was ripped out...

Comment: You said it yourself, it's a single sheet, and as such either a) Laxmidi has a T or G that he can tie in to, or b) he's overcomplicating the process. In either case my answer provides details on either situation.

Comment: Since the subfloor goes down before the walls go up, the odds that a sheet lines up with the room are just about zero.